# EditText without format

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, string-formatting, copy-paste

I am trying copy a password from Chrome Browser (in Android) into a EditText but it always copy the format, including two space at the end.

In XML file.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/signin_etPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:padding="8dp"/>
```

My password is

```
RLqGQQa3
```

but when I call to getText() it return:

```
 RLqGQQa3
```

with a space at start, and two at end.

**These occur only when I copy the password from browser**

Comment: you can use trim() method to remove unwanted spaces..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Paste without rich text formatting into EditText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24758698/paste-without-rich-text-formatting-into-edittext)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

### [`trim()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29)

> To Remove white space characters from the beginning and end of the string.

```
getText().toString().trim();
```

Comment: I can't do this because the passwords can contain spaces.
Thanks you anyway.

Comment: @cpalosrejano there is no password to starting and ending with space.

Answer (score 0):

In your class, do this:

```
String  signin_etPassword = EditTextinput.getText().toString();

signin_etPassword= signin_etPassword.trim();
```

This will remove only the spaces at the beginning or end of the String. Middle of the password will remain.

Comment: I can't do this. Passwords can contain spaces. Facebook and Twitter allow you do this.

Comment: you want to copy the spaces or not?

Comment: No. The problem is that EditText copy entire format from browser (including line breaks, strong text, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is how to paste without format.

This will remove formatting every time you change text, even on paste.

```
final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            CharacterStyle[] toBeRemovedSpans =
                    s.getSpans(0, s.length(), MetricAffectingSpan.class);

            for (int i = 0; i < toBeRemovedSpans.length; i++)
                s.removeSpan(toBeRemovedSpans[i]);

        }

    });
```

Adapted from this answer:
[Paste without rich text formatting into EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24758698/paste-without-rich-text-formatting-into-edittext)

Comment: If this question is a duplicate of the linked question, please flag it as a duplicate instead of leaving an answer to that effect. If it is not a duplicate, please leave a complete answer to this question instead of a link-only answer.

Comment: josilber: I don't have enough points to mark questions as duplicates, however, I have flagged it as such. Tnx for pointing it out.

Comment: Downvote? What for? For providing a way to the answer?